# Update http timeouts properly

Tags: java, multithreading, http, connection-timeout

I am trying to get HTTP codes from websites.
When I parse sites without threads, one-by-one, everything is fine.
But if I use threads, sometimes I receive

```
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
```

at

```
URL url = new URL(rset.getString("url"));
```

I think that the problem is in timeouts, and tried to break the cycle if timeout is > then I want.

```
if (connection.getConnectTimeout()>10)
{
    System.out.println("timeout");
    break;
}
```

But it seems that it never works. What am I doing wrong? Thank you. The full part of problem code is below.

```
static class JThread extends Thread {

    JThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println("hello");
                URL url = new URL(rset.getString("url"));
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getConnectTimeout()>10)
                {
                    System.out.println("timeout");
                    break;
                }
                //Thread.sleep(1000);

                int code = connection.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(code);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Thread stopped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get HTTP codes from websites. When I parse sites without threads, one-by-one, everything is fine. But if I use threads, sometimes I receive
>   `java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set`
>   at
>   `URL url = new URL(rset.getString("url"));`

This has nothing to do with HTTP timeouts. The exception you are getting is because you are trying to get the "url" column from a database row after you have already read all the results (and there are no more results to read).

You say this only happens when you use multiple threads. It looks like a thread enters the while loop (`rset.next()` is true). Then another thread calls `rset.next()` (moving past the end of the result set), gets false, and doesn't enter the loop. Then the first thread tries to get the URL, but you've already gone past the last result.

You should synchronize access to the ResultSet (or any object) if it is shared between multiple threads, but it would probably be better to just not share the ResultSet between threads. A better way to split the work would be to have a single thread get the URLs from the database, and 1 or more threads do the HTTP connection (e.g. thread pool, new thread per URL, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the calls to `ResultSet.next()` and check beforehand if it has been exhausted.

Now you have two threads calling it the same time and the first one gets the last row and the next one tries to get a row when the result set is already exhausted.